# Printing all environment value in C

Tags: c, environment-variables

So i get all environment variables:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
  for (char **env = envp; *env != 0; env++)
  {
    char *thisEnv = *env;
    printf("%s\n", thisEnv);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

How do I get all environment variables **value** (only value) in C.

I know that `getenv` can be used , but i don't know how use it in `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Printing the *value* only is simple - just find the first instance of `=`, and increment the pointer by one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    for (char **env = envp; *env != 0; env++)
    {
        char *pair = *env;
        char *value = strchr(pair, '=');
        if (value != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", value + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now, if you need to get the *variable name* as a null-terminated string, that is more tricky - because you shouldn't perhaps modify the environment variables in place, so you'd have to copy the name to another array.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
for (char **env = envp; *env != 0; env++)
{
    char *thisEnv = *env;
    printf("%s\n", strchr(thisEnv, '=')+1);
}
```

Perhaps?

Note that this assumes there are no empty environment variables on your system.